# How to refer to absolute paths in fish?

Tags: cygwin, fish

I'm trying to get fish to recognize an absolute path, either when changing directories or when giving an input to a program. I'm used to typing an absolute path as "C:/..." but in fish the only way I can get it to recognize an absolute path is to write instead "//owner-pc/...". If I do this when I'm changing directories, C:/ is replaced by /o/ thereafter. What is going on here - How are paths represented in fish?

In particular, how do I refer to a file on a different drive D:/ by its absolute path? What if I want to cd to a directory on a different drive?

(I am using Fish on Windows, with Cygwin.)

Comment: Fish on Windows? Under Cygwin, perhaps?

Comment: Yes. I modified the question.

Comment: You'll want to investigate the [`cygpath`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygpath) utility

Answer (score 0):

The cygwin `mount` command (provided you haven't made any changes) should display the absolute paths to your local drives.  `fish` should be able to properly reference the defaults like `/cygdrive/d`.